# What PDO function is equal to db::getOne

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am wondering what PDO function that is equal to the db::getOne?
I have this i need to change to PDO:

```
$count = db::getOne($query,$id,$showU['id']);
```

Comment: And what is `db::getOne`? What is `$id` and what is `$showU['id']`?

Comment: @elusive: PEAR's `DB` class I suspect

Comment: @Bolt Just a function that saves you from repetitive typing of prepare, execute and fetch. Just a little programming. Far unachievable thing for the most of local folks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$st = $pdodb->prepare($query);
$st->bindValue('id', $id);
$count = $st->fetchColumn();
```

This assumes you use named parameters which are always better than positional parameters IMO.

Comment: Thank for the answer, I made this question of out this answer, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359642/php-making-cleaner-shorter-code/4360286#4360286 , because I do not know what getOne and I needed it in PDO. But will this do it?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to provide more info but im going to assume that `id` and `$showU['id']` are params to be bound to `$query` and that `getOne` retruns a single record. If these assumptions are correct you would do something like:

```
$query = "SELECT count(id) as nb_records FROM your_table_name WHERE id = :id AND uID = :uid";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':uid' => $showU['id']);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

You could of course chain these.

Comment: Hi. Thank for the answer, I made this question of out this answer, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359642/php-making-cleaner-shorter-code/4360286#4360286 , because I do not know what getOne and I needed it in PDO. But will this do it?

Comment: execute returns boolean, not a statement object. Correct code would be 

`if ($stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':uid' => $showU['id'])) {
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
} `

Comment: @Tim corrected... surprised no on including myself caught that.

Answer (score -2):

It's a [user-defined](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) function. One can use not only ready-made functions, but also create new ones. So, getOne is of this kind. It has nothing to do with PDO or other library. It's rather of your own library. But of course, it can be made by using PDO as well.

You can adopt [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725879/fetchall-helper-function-using-pdo/3725962#3725962) to make a similar one which returns scalar value instead of array. But it seems you do not quite understand the meaning and the benefits (no offense - it's just matter of experience), so, nevermind. This function is not obligatory, it's just to make your code shorter and cleaner.
Programming, in general, stands for eliminating repetitions. Most of local folks aren't programmers but rather copy/pasters. Most of them just don't care of code size or readability. Not quite bad, as long as their code works. So, you can go this way too.

The only purpose of this function is to do less work for you and make your code more readable. It doesn't affect any results. So, it's not obligatory.